# Некорректное отображение ListView

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день,создан `ListView` со счетчиком на 100 строк.Позиции элементов идут не по порядку,а вразброс и повторяются.При включении приложения,все отображается корректно,при прокрутке начинается хаос (рандомные значения позиции).Как исправить проблему?

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private String[] mList;


public ListAdapter(Context context,String[]list){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mList = list;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
   static TextView txtItem;
   static ProgressButton btnList;
   ImageView imageView;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        ViewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvListView);
        ViewHolder.btnList = (ProgressButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivListItem);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ViewHolder.txtItem.setText(getItem(position));

    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int i) {
    return mList[i];
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

---

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String[] list = new String[100];
static float ratio;
static int row;
private  static final String TAG = "myLog";


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    initList(list);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,list);

    if (listView != null) {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                intent.putExtra("ratio",ratio);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }




}


public void initList(String[] list){
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        list[i]=i+" ";
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onSettingsMenuClick(MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 viewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvListView);
 viewHolder.btnList = (ProgressButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
 viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivListItem);
```

Исправьте на маленькую букву

Comment: Ошибка крылась в _"static"_                                                                           public static class ViewHolder {
   static TextView txtItem;
   static ProgressButton btnList;
   ImageView imageView;